# Ruby objects deserialization from Json

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3.2

(Disclaimer: New to Rails here)

Say I have a Rails ActiveRecord Model that responds to "id":

```
User.first.id # => 22
```

My life has changed, and now I need to get this same object via JSON call, and I want minimal code changes.

I do this:

```
uri = URI.parse("http://localhost:3001/user/")
uri.query = "query=id#{user_id}"
@user = JSON.parse(open(uri).read)
```

I can now do:

```
@user["id"]
```

However, this is not good enough because it would mean too many changes.
Is there any way to turn this into a real User object? or something that will act like one in a simple one (I probably can create a dummy object with constructor, but I'm looking for something that will do it for me, and I suspect there is a simple Rails-way for it).

Comment: It would be helpful to know more about what you are attempting to do. You are passing a user between two rails apps via json? What do need to do with the User in the receiving system that makes it need to be an AR object?

Comment: I have the same ActiveRecord Model on two separated systems. I am calling User.find(:id) on one system, to_json it, and than want to reconstruct/deserialize the ActiveRecord Model again on the receiving system, from the JSON. I was hoping I can do Model.build(json_obj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a possible solution to this problem:

https://github.com/sprysoft/json_object

However, I realized I actually need the original ActiveRecord Model and not a dummy object..

That said, to my specific question, above gem is a possible solution.